# Image won't resize after creating hover on images on Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover, resize

While adding a hover on feature for my images, the files i was trying it on ended up not matching the circle appearance that all my other sections have.

Here is the code for a section called coworking, no hover. Following that is the code for a section called virtual office, with a hover.

```
<li>
    <img class="alignnone wp-image-241 size-thumbnail" 
         src="https://liveprimary.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/coworking_dark-1-300x300.jpg"
         alt="" width="300" height="300" />
    </a>
    <h4>Coworking
        </a>Starting at $300
    </h4>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://staging.liveprimary.com/virtual-memberships/">
        <img class="alignnone wp-image-242 size-thumbnail" 
           src="http://staging.liveprimary.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/offices_dark.jpg" 
           onmouseover="this.src='http://staging.liveprimary.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/offices_light.jpg'" 
           onmouseout="this.src='http://staging.liveprimary.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/offices_dark.jpg'"
           alt="" width="300" height="300" 
        />
    </a>

    <h4>
        <a data-open="modal-virtual-memberships">Virtual Office
        </a>Starting at $80
    </h4>
</li>
```

When displayed on the site, coworking and virtual office's circle format is different in size.

I tried to adjust the width and height of the virtual office section but it did not work.

Staging site: http://staging.liveprimary.com/membership/
Password (if asked): Pr1m@ry!

Any ideas? I appreciate the help immensely!

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a demo or site url ??

Comment: just added it to the post!

Comment: Please call this image based on full one:
http://staging.liveprimary.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/offices_light-300x300.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one issue occurred because of you have called full (large) image path.
Please replace with this.

Light : http://staging.liveprimary.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/offices_light-300x300.jpg

Dark : http://staging.liveprimary.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/offices_dark-300x300.jpg

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `virtual office's circle img` size is different. And it's width and height not equal.

[image]

All other `img siz` is same `300*300`. 
[image]

When you try to create `circle img` it's better to use `same width and height images` .It's code method.

Comment: If you want to check it's really about the image problem, you can simply change the url of `virtual office's circle` with `coworking img`.

Comment: thank you!! yes youre right! it was the size. im still learning so thanks for the heads up!